# React Array in State updating late

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state, updating

What I am trying to do is update an array in state by adding a string of the name of the button the user pressed. The user has several buttons so after pressing them all I should be left with an array of strings correlating to the user's button presses.

First I give the user an alert telling them which food was added then I simply attempt to append the name of that food to the array in state. After which I pass that array back to the parent component to update a similar array there.

The problem I am getting is that when I press on one of the food options the array in state does not update, but i do get the correct alert. When I try a second food addition the array in state updates with the first option I selected. From then on every time I try to add a food Item the array in state updates with the food I selected before it.

I believe the problem is that I am updating state in a way that React does not do imminently. I know that state updates are not guaranteed in React.

Sorry for the long post, thank you for your time.

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.scss";
import FoodData from "./foodData.json";

class Food extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foodData: [],
      addedFoods: []
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Build a new array of objects from FoodData
    const newFoodData = FoodData.map(
      ({ name, pic, serving, calories, sugar, protien }, index) => ({
        id: index,
        name,
        pic,
        serving,
        calories,
        sugar,
        protien
      })
    );
    // Assign the new object to state
    this.setState({ foodData: newFoodData });
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    alert("Added " + e.target.name);
    this.setState(
      {
        addedFoods: [...this.state.addedFoods, e.target.name]
      },
      this.props.updateAddedFoods(this.state.addedFoods)
    );
  }

  render() {
    const displayFood = () => {
      let foodItems = []; // Crate an array
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.foodData.length; i++) {
        foodItems.push(
          // push item to array through the loop
          <div className="food-card" key={i}>
            <img src={require(`${this.state.foodData[i].pic}`)} />
            <ul>
              <li>{this.state.foodData[i].name}</li>
              <li>Serving: {this.state.foodData[i].serving}</li>
              <li>Calories: {this.state.foodData[i].calories}</li>
              <li>Sugar: {this.state.foodData[i].sugar}</li>
              <li>Protien: {this.state.foodData[i].protien}</li>
            </ul>
            <button
              onClick={this.handleClick}
              name={this.state.foodData[i].name}
            >
              Add
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
      return foodItems;
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="food-container">
          {!this.state.foodData.length ? <h1>Loading ...</h1> : displayFood()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Food;
```

Comment: Hello! Just to be sure.. I see that in `handleClick(e)` you run a callback `this.props.updateAddedFoods`. Could you please, in that callback, add a `console.log(this.state.addedFoods)`? Just to see if the state passed to that function is already updated or not, because the problem might be in the way you update the state in `handleClick`

Comment: Sure I will give it a shot right now... And I get the exact same thing. First time I try to add a food item the console log prints out an empty array which should have the just added food. Then when I try to add another food item the console log prints out an array with one item, the one I tried to add first.

Comment: Uhm ok, I'm adding an answer with an example, let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for helping me out but it is working. I do appreciate it though. If I could up vote you i would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second argument for `setState` should be a function and not a function call. Also it is better to use `setState(oldState => newState)` when new state is based on the old one:

```
  handleClick(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    alert("Added " + name);
    this.setState(oldState => ({
        addedFoods: [...oldState.addedFoods, name]
      }),
      () => this.props.updateAddedFoods(this.state.addedFoods)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the input and sorry for the long response I am trying it now.... When I make the change I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null". Trying to trouble shoot right now, but you are right about the state change for sure.

Comment: Try removing `alert` or saving `e.target.name` before it. React reuses event objects and it might get cleaned before `setState`

Comment: Still getting the same error on the "addedFood: [...oldState.addedFoods, e.target.name]" line with or without the alert.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The event object stored in `e` is cleared before it gets to the callback inside `setState`.

Comment: YEEET you got it my man. I wish I could up vote your answer. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous, so when you pass `this.state.addedFoods` as an argument to `this.props.updatedAddedFoods` you’re passing the state before you changed it. Since it seems like you are duplicating data, might I suggest only the parent has the array of food and passes it as a prop to the child?

Comment: That is a really great design change that I should make you are totally right and I will do that right now.

Answer (score 0):

So, as I said in the comment, I think `handleClick()` is the problem, more exactly how you update the state.
Can you try to write that function as follow:

```
handleClick(e) {
    const newAddedFoods = Object.assign([], this.state.addedFoods);
    newAddedFoods.push(e.target.name);

    this.setState({addedFoods: newAddedFoods }, () => this.props.updateAddedFoods(newAddedFoods));
}
```

Though, @Iarz is totally right: it seems you have the same data both in parent Component and children Component. Just keep it in the parent component, and pass to the children the data and a function to update it.

Comment: 100% right about the data duplicates in parent and child. Growing pains lol. Thanks for all the advice.